# Rspec not finding parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

Ok so in my actual mailer code, I've resorted to the temporary stopgap below:

```
  if Rails.env == "test" 
    @requestlist["#{index}"] = {"#{Itemlist.find_by_id(b.itemlist_id).name}" => "#{Inventory.find_by_id(b.inventory_id)}"}
  else
    @requestlist["#{index}"] = {"#{Itemlist.find_by_id(b.itemlist_id).name}" => "#{Inventory.find_by_id(b.inventory_id).signup.email}"}
  end
```

It's super weird because:

1. If I use test the second statement, I get a `NoMethodError`, 'signup', for `NilClass`
2. But obviously, since the first statement is passing, `Inventory` is clearly not `Nil` (I mean it would be different if the `Signup` object just weren't being found...)
3. Also I've tested this by hand and the mailer is able to retrieve `.signup.email` just fine
4. Furthermore, other tests that require retrieval of `signup.email` for `Inventory` pass just fine

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why don't you just write?

```
@requestlist[index] = { Itemlist.find_by_id(b.itemlist_id).name => Inventory.find_by_id(b.inventory_id).signup.email }
```

Secondly, didn't you suspect that NoMethodError for NilClass may mean that

```
Inventory.find_by_id(b.inventory_id)
```

doesn't return any rows from database?

And thirdly, it that `if` and attempt to "fix`tests? (btw you can write`Rails.env.test?`)

Comment: Point 1 is just me being stupid. I fixed the code. Point 3 I get now, yes it's my attempt to "fix" the test to get a green light, because otherwise I know that I'll look at it one day and be very confused by the red. Regarding Point 2, I don't understand, I am retrieving a row from the database, because in the fixed version of the test, there is an object that is printing just fine for `Inventory.find_by_id(b.inventory_id)`

Comment: Change second to this line `Inventory.find(b.inventory_id)` and you will start getting exception because this id will not be found in db (`find_by_id` returns nil, you shouldn't be using that without strong reason)

Comment: And to fix the problem with inventory not found by id I guess you have to show your models. Do you have any validations in place?

Comment: I don't have any validations in place that would hinder this. Ironically, I have a validation that says Inventory has to belong to Signup... which means that the fact that the Inventory exists at all when testing means that it must be associated with some Signup. Sorry I'm a little confused by your other suggestion? Anyways, when I make the change to just `find` I get: error: `Couldn't find Inventory without an ID`

Comment: Exactly, which confirms my suspicion. `Couldn't find Inventory without an ID` means that `b.inventory_id` is either nil or empty, now you have to debug back to the place you set it and find a but in there. Where does the `b` come from?